# When to use something like (id<UISearchBarDelegate>)self?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I've seen this in some areas of code that I am working with.

```
searchBar.delegate = (id<UISearchBarDelegate>)self;
```

My question is...

Why not just make the current class a delegate of `UISearchBar` by adding `<UISearchBarDelegate>` in the interface of the class?

Are there times when the above code is better than having the class be a delegate?.

Both ways work for me, but I'd like to learn why I may want to use one over the other.

Comment: "Why not just make the current class a delegate of UISearchBar by adding in the interface of the class?" - just do it. The code in question is a horrible hack.

Comment: @H2CO3 don't you ever sleep or eat Oo ?

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis No, I'm a ghost.

Comment: The simple answer is never, apple documentation shows how you should set up a delegate

Comment: Just because something 'works' doesn't mean you should do it. Always make the class a delegate by adding it to the interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cast approach could be considered a cheat. It would be used if the delegate class didn't want to publicly declare the protocol conformance (but then why is it being publicly set as the delegate). Or if the delegate class didn't implement all of the required methods so declaring the protocol conformance would result in warnings.

Generally the better approach is to declare the protocol conformance (either publicly (.h) or privately (.m)).

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  Since I had seen it several times in the code that I've been tasked to work on, I thought that maybe I had been missing out on something.  I appreciate the answers!  Now I know that the way I had thought to be "correct" was correct, and that this code just kind of blows.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using the `UISearchBarDelegate`  in your .h like

```
@interface ScaryBugData < UISearchBarDelegate>

@property (strong) UISearchBar * searchBar;
@end
```

then in your .m file then you must do the following to silence the warning

```
searchBar.delegate = (id<UISearchBarDelegate>)self;
```